# Почему вылетает _block_type_is_valid при использовании QCameraInfo::availableCameras?

Tags: c++, qt

Win7, VS2013, QT 5.4

```
#include <QtWidgets\QtWidgets>
#include <QtMultimedia\QCameraInfo> 

#pragma comment(lib, "Qt5Widgets.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Qt5Multimedia.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Qt5Core.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QList<QCameraInfo> cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
    QDialog dlg;
    dlg.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Запускается и показывает диалог, но при его закрытии получаю _block_type_is_valid в отладчике. В консольном окне пусто. Если убрать `QList<QCameraInfo> cameras ...` - все ок. Не могу понять что же я делаю не так :-(

**UPD1**: вылетает только если подключена камера.

Comment: Проверьте на другой версии Qt/компилятора. Возможно, просто баг.

Comment: @alexolut выяснилось что вылетает только если камера подключена. Без камеры все в порядке.

Comment: а другие версии удалось проверить?

Comment: @alexolut Без камеры не падали, так что потащу камеру после праздников...

Comment: т.е. с камерой падает на разных версиях Qt и компилятора?

Comment: @alexolut Нет. Без камеры не падает на разных версиях, а с камерой тестировалось только у меня.